# How can I insert nodes in a GPathResult?

Tags: groovy

It would seem that GPathResult returns a list of nodes which is the same for each iteration. How can I insert nodes from one iteration and find them in the next, as shown in the example below?

```
def messageNodes = [] as HashSet
def inputRoot = new XmlSlurper().parse(xmlFile)
inputRoot.testsuite.list().each { suiteNode ->
  suiteNode.children().list().each { caseNode ->
    caseNode.children().list().each { messageNode ->
      messageNodes << messageNode
    }
  }
}

inputRoot.testsuite.list().each { suiteNode ->
  suiteNode.children().list().each { caseNode ->
    caseNode.children().list().each { messageNode ->
      assert messageNodes.contains(message)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That code isn't `inserting` nodes...  But as it stands (trying to find nodes are the same between scans), it won't work either due to the way `XmlSlurper` works...

When you call `children()` on a `GPathResult`, you end up with an iterator that returns new instances of `NodeChild`.  Because these are new instances, they cannot be compared to the last time you saw them (as their hashcode will be different)

If you change your code to use `XmlParser` like so:

```
def messageNodes = []
def inputRoot = new XmlParser().parse(xmlFile)
inputRoot.testsuite.'*'.'*'.each { messageNode ->
  messageNodes << messageNode
}

inputRoot.testsuite.'*'.'*'.each { messageNode ->
  println messageNode.hashCode()
  assert messageNodes.contains(messageNode)
}
```

I believe it works as you'd expect (I had to guess at your xml format though, as you didn't show us what it was in the question)

As an addition, you can change the lines

```
inputRoot.testsuite.'*'.'*'.each { messageNode ->
  messageNodes << messageNode
}
```

to

```
messageNodes.addAll( inputRoot.testsuite.'*'.'*' )
```

for the same functionality...

It should also be noted that XmlSlurper doesn't store internal state in a navigable way, so if you add nodes, you cannot find them unless you write the xml out and read it back in.  If this is the sort of thing you're aiming for, `XmlParser` is probably also the better route